# css child selector does not work towards th elements in a thead

Tags: css, html, css-selectors, html-table

I have the following table:

```
<table class="table-container">
  <thead class="table-heading">
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-body">
    <tr>
      <td class="table-column">test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If i do the following in css:

```
.table-body > tr > td {
  padding: 25px;
}
```

it works without any problems.

But if i do the following in css:

```
.table-heading > th {
  padding: 25px;
}
```

it does not work even though the th element is a child of the thead element.
Does anyone know why this does not work ?

Comment: You don't actually have those classes in your markup, do you? I really don't see why you couldn't just use `tbody` and `thead` in your selectors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have missed the `<tr>` element within the `<thead>`. Modern web browsers add the `<tr>` dynamically, therefore `.table-heading > th` won't match the `th`s since they are not direct descendants of `.table-heading` element but the `tr`.

For instance, try `.table-heading > tr > th` selector.

```css
.table-heading > tr > th {
  padding: 25px;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-container">
  <thead class="table-heading">
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
    <th>test</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="table-body">
    <tr>
      <td class="table-column">test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
      <td>test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: And yet another reason not to trust tables; they're never quite what you think they are.

Comment: Thanks. I've being running it through w3c validation some times before but i thought i was writing valid enough html at this point..but clearly missed that i needed tr also in the thead. @Katana if you know about a better way to present data from a database that fits the characteristics of a table then please do let me know

Comment: @sundance No, sorry for being smarmy; honestly for actual data presentation, tables do tend to make sense. It's just that many web developers use tables in situations where they should be avoided.

Answer (score 5):

Because your HTML is invalid and most browsers correct it by wrapping your `<th>`s in `<tr>`s. So the correct selector would be:

```
.table-heading > tr > th {
  padding: 25px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xbumz6k4/1)**